# Many-to-many relationship with self table Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am having a table with a self-referencing column with many-to-many relations

```
class PanelUser(core_models.TimestampedModel):
    assigned = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="panelusers", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**Problem**
I have three records A, B, C and
if I and assigning
**A** = B
then is automatically assigned **B** = A

I don't understand why this is happing, how I fix it.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ManyToManyField` takes a [`symmetrical`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) parameter when using "self", when set to `False` it prevents the behaviour you describe and makes the relationship asymmetrical

```
assigned = models.ManyToManyField(
    "self",
    related_name="panelusers",
    blank=True,
    symmetrical=False
)
```